# solr select a top level nested child from multiple nested documents

Tags: solr, nested-documents

I have indexed document with below structure in solr

```
{
  "id": "1",
   "name":"name",
  ...more properties
  "likes": [
    {"user": "user1", "comment": "Great!"},
    {"user": "user2", "comment": "Awesome!"}
  ],
  "comments": [
    {"user": "user3", "comment": "Nice post!"},
    {"user": "user4", "comment": "I agree!"}
  ],
  ...other nested arrays
}
```

i want to list all non nested properies(id,name etc..) and only selected nested documents(eg: id,name,comments(top 50 sorted by some crieteria)).
i see field list(`fl`) allows `childFilter` and `limit`, but i cant find how can i return only selected nested child.